# Jhipster-registry showing > Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, jhipster-registry

I have deployed Jhispter-registry on gce (vm), and keycloak is again deployed on another gce vm. The keycloak is configured properly and up and running. But when trying to access the registry page, it throws following error;

"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://keycloa.vm.ip.masked:8080/auth/realms/jhipster"

any hints/ pointers to resolve the issue. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: what have you done for that please?